# React and DRF , JWT authentication login fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest API with JWT authentication and React for the front.

When trying to log in a user, my request get's a 403 where it should return a token pair.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axiosInstance from "../axiosApi";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: "", password: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitWThen = this.handleSubmitWThen.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = axiosInstance.post("/token/obtain/", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      });
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
        "JWT " + response.data.access;
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access);
      localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", response.data.refresh);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  handleSubmitWThen(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axiosInstance
      .post("/token/obtain/", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
      .then((result) => {
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
          "JWT " + result.data.access;
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", result.data.access);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", result.data.refresh);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Login
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Username:
            <input
              name="username"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Password:
            <input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

And the axios code:

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json",
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

the error when I hit the submit button on the login page.

```
login.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined
    at Login.handleSubmit (login.js:68)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:306)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:389)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:414)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3278)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3287)
```

I understand there's something wrong with my handlesubmit function that the call is not being made.

printing reponse.data to the console:

```
class Login ...

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = axiosInstance.post("/token/obtain/", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      });
    console.log(response.data)
    ...
```

Results in a rejected Promise:
[image: console output]

Comment: have you tried to console.log your response ?  From a quick guess, here the code is being asynchronous and at the time you want to set response.data fields in localStorage, you don't have yet the object returned from your call.

Comment: why don't you use the function handleSubmitWThen instead of handleSubmit ? just out of curiosity